# Why does overflow-y:auto prevent the grandchild divs from overflowing x?

Tags: html, css

Given the following markup and CSS, I expect that the red squares (`.a`) overflow and appear over the black wrapper, when their parent `.i` element is hovered. However, the `overflow-y: auto` style property on the parent of the `.i` elements is causing them to become cut-off when I hover their parent element.

The expected behavior is that the red square extends into the black wrapper element when its parent element is hovered. As of now, I can only achieve that when removing `overflow-y: auto` from `.l`.

Non-working example:

```css
.w {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: black;
}

.l {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.i {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.a {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  right: 0;
}

.i:hover .a {
  right: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="w">
  <div class="l">
    <div class="i">
      <div class="a"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="i">
      <div class="a"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="i">
      <div class="a"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Expected result:

```css
.w {
 height:500px;
 width:500px;
 background-color:black;
}

.l {
 width:50%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:lightgrey;
 /* overflow-y:auto; */
}

.i {
 position:relative;
 background-color:white;
 height:50px;
 width:100%;
}

.a {
 position:absolute;
 height:50px;
 width:50px;
 background-color:red;
 right:0;
}

.i:hover .a {
 right:-25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="w">
 <div class="l">
  <div class="i">
   <div class="a"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="i">
   <div class="a"></div>   
  </div>
  <div class="i">
    <div class="a"></div>  
  </div>
 </div>
 
</div>
```

I expect overflow-y to have no bearing on overflowing the x-axis.

Comment: Using `overflow-y` with any value other than `visible` establishes a new block-formatting context, and you therefore can't mix `visible` in one axis with anything else in the other axis.

Comment: possible duplicate of :https://stackoverflow.com/q/57007497/8620333

Comment: Thanks for the edit @TemaniAfif

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - Thank you for the explanation. Looks like I'll need to find a different way of going about this.